# Sprintf with string

Tags: c++

I am trying to display image from different locations. There are car, airplane, chair etc. files need to be display. I put those words (car, airplane) in a text file. I can read words but when I put them in sprintf, I get nonsense characters.
I can display the words with `cout<<*j<<endl;`. But `cout<<filename<<endl;` gives me weird result.

```
string words;
std::vector<string>list;
fstream file;
file.open("h.txt");
while(!file.eof())
{
    file >> words;
    list.push_back(words);
}
for(vector<string>::iterator j=list.begin(); j!=list.end(); j++)
{
    cout<<*j<<endl;
    for(i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        sprintf( filename,"D:\\101_ObjectCategories\\%s\\image_%04d.jpg",*j,i);
        cout<<filename<<endl;
```

Comment: Hääää? What do you want to achieve?? `std::cout` doesn't support 'image display'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C function `sprintf()` is oblivious of the C++ classes. If you really want to print a `std::string` using `sprintf()` you'll need to extract a C string:

```
sprintf(filename, "D:\\101_ObjectCategories\\%s\\image_%04d.jpg", j->c_str(), i);
```

You should also use `snprintf()` together with the size of the buffer you pass as `filename` to prevent overflow. Personally, I wouldn't really bother and rather using `std::ostringstream` in the first place:

```
std::ostringstream out;
out << "D:\\101_ObjectCategories\\" << *j << "\\image_"
    << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << i << ".jpg";
std::string filename = out.str();
```

(after including `<sstream>` and `<iomanip>`).

Answer (score 1):

Use must use *j.c_str():

```
sprintf( filename,"D:\\101_ObjectCategories\\%s\\image_%04d.jpg",*j.c_str(),i);
```

Otherwise, the string class itself is cast into a char* explicitly which is garbage of course :)